# Con un left join concatenar datos en la misma fila

Tags: sql, db2

Estoy buscando la forma de en vez de utilizar `UNION ALL`, ocupar otra forma para poder ver mi tabla en la misma fila, es decir por medio de la claveempresa quedaría así:

`8|9|origen numero 8|origen numero 9`

Esta es mi consulta:

```
SELECT
        G.ANOMBREOFICINA,
        OC.ADESTINOCORRIDA ,
        OT.HHORASALIDAINICIO AS HORA_SALIDA,
        OT.FFECHASALIDAINICIO,*    
    FROM    
               CVORGDESTCONECTADET OC
    INNER JOIN CVORGDESTCONECTA CD  ON CD.NCONSECUTIVO = OC.NCONSECUTIVO AND OC.NVIAJE = OC.NVIAJEPADRE
    INNER JOIN PSCORRIDASACTIVAS OT ON OT.NCLAVECORRIDA = OC.NCLAVECORRIDA AND OT.NREGENERACION = 0
    INNER JOIN GCOFICINAS G ON G.ACLAVEOFICINA = OC.ADESTINOCORRIDA AND OC.NCLAVEEMPRESA = G.NCLAVEEMPRESA
WHERE
        OC.AORIGENCORRIDA  = 'MTA'
    AND OC.LACTIVO = x'01'
    AND OC.NCLAVEEMPRESA IN (8, 38, 63, 9, 47, 64)
    AND OT.FFECHASALIDAINICIO = current_date
    AND OT.HHORASALIDAINICIO >= current_time - 1 MINUTE
UNION ALL
SELECT
    G.ANOMBREOFICINA,
    OC.ADESTINOCORRIDA,
    OT.HHORASALIDAINICIO AS HORA_SALIDA,
    OT.FFECHASALIDAINICIO,*
FROM
               CVORGDESTCONECTADET OC
    INNER JOIN CVORGDESTCONECTA CD  ON CD.NCONSECUTIVO = OC.NCONSECUTIVO AND OC.NVIAJE = OC.NVIAJEPADRE
    INNER JOIN PSCORRIDASACTIVAS OT ON OT.NCLAVECORRIDA = OC.NCLAVECORRIDA AND OT.NREGENERACION = 0
    INNER JOIN GCOFICINAS G ON G.ACLAVEOFICINA = OC.ADESTINOCORRIDA AND OC.NCLAVEEMPRESA = G.NCLAVEEMPRESA
WHERE
        OC.AORIGENCORRIDA  = 'MTY'
    AND OC.LACTIVO = x'01'
    AND OC.NCLAVEEMPRESA IN (8, 38, 63, 9, 47, 64)
    AND OT.FFECHASALIDAINICIO = current_date
   -- AND OT.HHORASALIDAINICIO >= current_time - 1 MINUTE    
ORDER BY HORA_SALIDA ASC
FETCH FIRST 552 ROWS ONLY FOR FETCH ONLY;
```

Comment: Hola. Desde la versión 9.7.5 puedes hacerlo con [**`LISTAGG()`**](https://www.ibm.com/docs/es/db2/11.5?topic=functions-listagg). En caso contrario, hay otras alternativas que emulan esta función. Revisa [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7188542/5587982) para más detalles.